# PHP regex to match Windows product key

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting (and failing) to write a PHP regex that will match a Windows product key in the form XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX (where X is an uppercase letter or a number).

I have come up with the following, but it is not doing quite what I expect (provided it actually *can do* what I expect!). I consider myself pretty well versed in PHP, but regexes are a particular weak point for me.

```
([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})
```

What I am actually after is it to pass `ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY` but to fail `ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXYZ` (notice the last block has 6 characters).

**Bonus chatter:** Yes, I know that not all letters are valid in a Windows product key, but the important bit is that it validates the text has been entered in the correct format.

Comment: I'm by far not a Regex expert but what you've got looks fine to me. Have you tried adding a `^` to the front and a `$` to the end? What function(s) are you using to apply the regex? What is not working?

Comment: Why are you even so obsessed with the correct format? A good setup routine (and I believe the one Windows uses does too) automatically puts dashes in there and ignores whitespace and capitalization.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel - this is a system at work which manages many license keys in many different formats. We've had several instances recently where the key has been entered into the system wrong (e.g 6 blocks of X instead of 5), and lowercase keys look ugly among a load of uppercase ones. A different regex is applied, depending on what software title the license is for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you're missing is position anchors in your regex. Currently, the regex will match that pattern anywhere in a string. The string could by "my product key is XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX and my name is Bob" and your regex would match. What you need is

```
^([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})-([A-Z1-9]{5})$
```

The `^` matches only the beginning of the string and `$` matches only the end.

Comment: You can shorten it to `^[A-Z1-9]{5}(-[A-Z1-9]{5}){4}$`, though.

Comment: I don't actually use PHP so I wasn't sure if that would allow getting all the match groups or just the last one.

Comment: Well, the question didn't sound like they'd be using the groups; looked more like validation to me. But yes, if you need the groups, then it isn't going to work in the shortened form.

Comment: Ah is that really all it was! @Johannes Rössel - I'll give that a shot too. Thanks to both of you.